# UITableView visible in IOS7 but not visible in IOS6

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios6, uiscrollview, hidden

I have a `UIScrollView` with a small `UITableView` inside. In `iOS-7` everything works perfectly, but in `iOS-6` the table view does not show at all, completely invisible. 
Everything is instantiated, the delegate and data source methods are called, but the `UITableView` just not appears. A blank space and nothing else.

Anyone has any idea why this might be happening?

Update:

It's just the native UITableView with the native cells.

Here's some example code:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [_gridTableData count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *gridCellId = @"gridCellID";

    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:gridCellId];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue2 reuseIdentifier:gridCellId];
        [cell.textLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:12]];
        [[cell textLabel] setText:_gridTableNames[[indexPath row]]];
        [cell.detailTextLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:12]];
        [[cell detailTextLabel] setText:_gridTableData[[indexPath row]]];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: It would be good if you could post some screenshots, both from your code and from what u see in simulator ! You probably are missing something somewhere !

Comment: I wish I could, but I don't have the necessary reputation yet, I using a new account. As soon as I'm able I will post the screenshots. Anyway, in ios6 there's just a black space, completely disappear :/

Comment: Try using some log statements to print out the size of the 1. the tableview frame, 2. the scrollview frame, and 3. the scroll view content size.  The second thing is that apple strongly discourages nesting scrollable views. ie: don't put a tableview inside of a scroll view. I advise you to, if possible, to make simply a tableview with custom header and footer views.

Comment: I tried some log statements! And I noticed that in IOS6, after the viewDidLoad method, the UiTableView's frame height turns 0. Automatically. In IOS7 everything works normal. Weird behaviour :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some recommended log statements, I've found where's the problem:

In iOS6 the height of the UITableView's frame turns to 0. During "viewDidLoad" the height is correct(94p), but after that the height is always 0.

But I really don't know why this is happening. In iOS7 the UITableView's height never changes.

So I can "fix" it by re-setting the UITableView's frame height in "viewDidLayoutSubviews", for example. But if anyone has a clean way of fixing this, or knows the origin of this behaviour, it will be appreciated.

Comment: It is incorrect to set frames in viewDidLoad. viewWillLayoutSubviews is the correct place to set the frames of your subviews.

Comment: @AaronBrager I'm setting the frame in viewDidLayoutSubviews. But the strange situation is that, from some logs, I've noticed that during viewDidLoad the tablview frame height is correct, but after that it's somehow re-setted to 0. (not by me)

Comment: Something bogus is going on.  I've never heard of having to reset the size of the table view.  I'm guessing you've not located the fundamental problem.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that in iOS 7, by default, the background of cells is white. In 6 and earlier it's transparent. This means that if you have black text in a table that overlays a black background it will be invisible in 6 and earlier. (Seeing some screen shots would help.)

Comment: I wish I could, but I don't have the necessary reputation yet, I using a new account. As soon as I'm able I will post the screenshots. The Tableview consists of white background with black text (native cells). I've added some example code!

Comment: @6rod9 - So where/how do you set the table background?  (Try `cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];`, around where you set textLabel.text.  See if that makes the text show up on 6.)